# Explain this step in logarithms

Tags: logarithms

I saw the following in a book:

> $$\log_{1/2}x \geq \log_{1/3}x$$
>
> $$\Rightarrow \log_2x \geq \log_3x$$

Now, none of the properties I know deals with fractional bases. What's the justification behind this step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\log_{1/k}x = \frac{\ln x}{\ln \frac{1}{k}} = -\frac{\ln x}{\ln k} = -\log_{k}x$$
so
$$\log_{1/2}x \geq \log_{1/3}x \Rightarrow \log_2x \leq \log_3x$$

Comment: But the inequality is not matching. Does that mean it's a mistake in the book?

Comment: Either in the book or in my answer. However, trying with $x=1/10$, it looks like the book is wrong.

Comment: Your answer seems fine.

Comment: I'm not so sure. At $x = 1/10, \log_{1/2}x = 3.32$ and $\log_{1/3}x = 2.1$. Thus, $\log_{1/2}x > \log_{1/3}x$. Also, if we consider $\log_x2 = -0.3$ and $\log_x3 = -0.47$, we see that $\log_x2 > \log_x3$. Or have I made a mistake somewhere?

Comment: Is there a property that says $-\log_ab = \log_ba$? I don't think so, but it would make life so much more easy.

Comment: Well, as a matter of fact, for any $x> 1$ the first inequality is false; so the implication trivially holds for $x > 1$ (and is also true for $x=1$). So the statement you are trying to prove is correct for $x\geq 1$ (but actually "empty").

Comment: @dotslash: for $x < 1$, $\log_{1/2}x \geq \log_{1/3}x$ but $\log_{2}x < \log_{3}x$.

Comment: @dotslash The RHS is reciprocal of what you have in comment 5

Comment: @ClementC. Actually the question revolves around establishing that $0 < x < 1$. Would that make the textbook correct?

Comment: No. The implication is **wrong** for $x\in(0,1)$, and **correct** for $x\in[1,\infty)$.

Answer (score 0):

First, let me start by saying that the second inequality in your original post is pointing in the wrong direction. Use your calculator with a fixed $x$ and check.

Let's think about what $\log_{1/2}x$ means. If $y = \log_{1/2}x$ then, by definition, $(1/2)^y = x$. Notice that $(1/2)^y \equiv 1/2^y$ and, assuming $x \neq 0$, we have $(1/2)^y = x \iff 2^y=1/x$. Going back to the definition of logs, if $2^y = 1/x$ then 
$$y = \log_2(1/x) \equiv \log_21-\log_2x \equiv - \log_2x$$
We started with $y = \log_{1/2}x$ and ended up with $y = -\log_2x$. It follows that $\log_{1/2}x\equiv-\log_2x$. Likewise, $\log_{1/3}x\equiv-\log_3x$. Hence:
$$\log_{1/2}x \ge \log_{1/3}x \iff -\log_2x \ge -\log_3x \iff \log_2x \le \log_3x$$

Comment: And what can we say about the value of $x$ is this case?